# Weblogic 12c WLST Create User offline

Tags: weblogic12c, wlst

I want to create New User (admin/admin123) and Domain (myapp) offline using WLST Script. I want to use template common/templates/wls/wls.jar to create the Domain

Please share me sample scripts to do the same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
readTemplate(".../wls.jar")
cd('Security')
cd('base_domain')
cd('User')
user=create("Jim","User")
user.setPassword("welcome1")
```